# Does Conversion Therapy cause harm?

Tags: sexuality

[There](http://www.faithinamerica.org/reparative-therapy/) [have](http://www.hrc.org/resources/entry/the-lies-and-dangers-of-reparative-therapy) [been](http://cswr.columbia.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/2010_vol1_pg8_horner.pdf) [many](http://www.drdoughaldeman.com/doc/ScientificExamination.pdf) [claims](http://www.livescience.com/50453-why-gay-conversion-therapy-harmful.html) that [conversion therapy/reparative therapy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_therapy) to convert homosexuals into heterosexuals is harmful or potentially harmful.

Does it actually cause harm?

Comment: Note: This question skirts/ignores a number of incredibly important side issues: (1) Does it *work*? (2) Is it *ethical*, even if it does work?

Comment: Have you read the articles that are referenced in MOU?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a very [scientific](http://www.apa.org/pi/lgbt/resources/therapeutic-response.pdf#__utma=149406063.220788723.1429797326.1429797326.1429797326.1&__utmb=149406063.1.10.1429797326&__utmc=149406063&__utmx=-&__utmz=149406063.1429797326.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)&__utmv=-&__utmk=31438271) report from American Psychological Association Task Force on the *Appropriate Therapeutic Responses to Sexual Orientation*, the question of

> Are SOCE harmful?

was studied.

Note that the scientific report has explicitly said:

> In our review, we considered **only peer-reviewed
>   research**, in keeping with current standards for
>   conducting scientific reviews (see Khan, Kunz, Kleijnen,
>   & Antes, 2003), **which exclude the grey literature and
>   lay material**.

Their report reviewed many experiments, they are summarized here:

Early Studies:

> Early research on efforts to change sexual orientation
>   focused heavily on interventions that include aversion
>   techniques. Many of these studies did not set out to
>   investigate harm. Nonetheless, **these studies provide
>   some suggestion that harm can occur from aversive
>   efforts to change sexual orientation**.

Nonexperimental Studies:

> In the study conducted by Bancroft (1969) , he reported
>   the **intervention had harmful effects on 50% of the
>   16 research subjects who were exposed to it**.  Quinn,
>   Harrison, and McAllister (1970) and Thorpe et al.
>   (1964) also reported **cases of debilitating depression,
>   gastric distress, nightmares, and anxiety.** Herman and
>   Prewett (1974) reported that following treatment, their
>   research participant began to engage in **abusive use of
>   alcohol that required his rehospitalization**.

Experimental Studies:

> In McConaghy and Barr’s (1973) experiment, **1
>   respondent of 46 subjects is reported to have lost all
>   sexual feeling and to have dropped out of the treatment
>   as a result**. **Two participants reported experiencing
>   severe depression**, and **4 others experienced milder
>   depression during treatment**. No other experimental
>   studies reported on iatrogenic effects.

Quasi-experimental Studies:

> None reported on adverse events.

Recent Studies:

> Some recent studies document that **there are people who
>   perceive that they have been harmed through SOCE**
>   (Beckstead & Morrow, 2004; Nicolosi et al., 2000;
>   Schaeffer et al., 2000; Schroeder & Shidlo, 2001; Shidlo
>   & Schroeder, 2002; Smith et al., 2004), **just as other
>   recent studies document that there are people who
>   perceive that they have benefited from it** (Beckstead &
>   Morrow, 2004; Nicolosi et al., 2000; Pattison & Pattison,
>   1980; Schaeffer et al., 2000; Spitzer, 2003).Many participants in studies by Beckstead and Morrow (2004) and Shidlo and Schroeder (2002) **described experiencing
>   first the positive effects and then experiencing or
>   acknowledging the negative effects later**.  Among
>   those studies reporting on the perceptions of harm, the
>   reported negative social and emotional consequences
>   include self-reports of **anger, anxiety, confusion,
>   depression, grief, guilt, hopelessness, deteriorated
>   relationships with family, loss of social support, loss
>   of faith, poor self-image, social isolation, intimacy
>   difficulties, intrusive imagery, suicidal ideation,
>   self-hatred, and sexual dysfunction**.

Conclusion:

> Studies from both periods
>   indicate that attempts to
>   change sexual orientation
>   **may cause or exacerbate
>   distress and poor mental
>   health in some individuals**,
>   including depression and
>   suicidal thoughts. The lack
>   of rigorous research on the
>   safety of SOCE represents
>   a serious concern, **as
>   do studies that report
>   perceptions of harm**

So, there is a correlational link between "conversion therapy" and "harm" but not a causal link. Note that this is not a question of whether "conversion therapy" works or not, but only whether it causes harm.